# while loop slows down over time

Tags: python, performance, while-loop, pyephem

I am calculating azimuth and elevation relative to me with Python, which then sends it to an Arduino via a Serial connection. The python program calculates the position, waits 1 second, calculates the position again and subtracts both values to see how much the position has changed in 1 second.
The program does this in a never ending `while True:` loop:

```
while True:
    home.date = datetime.utcnow()
    iss.compute(home)
    el = int(iss.alt * degrees_per_radian)    #elevation
    az = int(iss.az * degrees_per_radian)     #azimuth
    print("az: " + str(az), "el: " + str(el))  
    time.sleep(1)

    home.date = datetime.utcnow()
    iss.compute(home)
    az2 = int(iss.az * degrees_per_radian)
    az3 = az2 - az                          #position change in 1 second 
    print(az2, az3)

    str_pos = str(az3) + ";" + str(el) + '\n'
    byte_pos = str_pos.encode()
    port.write(byte_pos)
    print("data transmitted!")
    print("__________________")
```

Everything works fine for a few minutes, but then the code suddenly slows down and each step takes a few seconds. It also can't determine the difference between `az` and `az2`, always returning a zero, even though it's actually 1 or higher.

Comment: I cant know what happening, there could be one value getting ridiculously higher and higher, would suggest print(), all things, and look whats happening, when it slows down.

Comment: You need to narrow down which step is running slowly. Add timing code around the calls to `iss.compute()` and `port.write()`.

Comment: Is your Arduino actually reading the data?  Is it possible it is getting behind and the buffer fills up?  If you comment the `port.write`, do you still see it slow down?  Because the rest is just computation.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at it again and I'm pretty sure that `port.write` is the problem. It's the part that suddenly takes so long. What do you mean with "comment the `port.write`?